# What exactly goes wrong when using sort_values with inplace=True inside groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, in-place

Based on a recent question I came to wonder what *exactly* goes wrong when sorting a group using `inplace=True` inside a function applied to `groupby`.

### Example and problem

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'b'],
                   'B': [3, 2, 1]})

def func(x):
    x.sort_values('B', inplace=True)
    return x.B.max()

dfg = df.groupby('A')
dfg.apply(func)
```

This gives

```
A
a    3
b    3
```

while one would expect

```
A
a    3
b    1
```

Printing `x` inside the function shows that the function `func` is applied to the group `'a'` during each call (the group `'b'` is "replaced" entirely):

```py
def func(x):
    print(x)
    x.sort_values('B', inplace=True)
    return x.B.max()

# Output (including the usual pandas apply zero-call)
   A  B
0  a  3
1  a  2
   A  B
0  a  3
1  a  2
   A  B
1  a  2
0  a  3
```

### Solution to the problem

This issue can be fixed by performing the sort inside `func` like `x = x.sort_values('B')`. In this case, everything works as expected.

### Question

Now to my conceptual problem: As a first thought I would expect

- that `inplace` modifies the DataFrame/DataFrameGroupBy itself, while the assignment `x = x.sort_values('B')` creates a copy
- that this is the groupby equivalent of modifying a list while looping over it

*However, inspection of both the Dataframe df and the DataFrameGroupBy instance dfg reveals that they are unchanged after the `apply`, which suggests that the problem is **not** the modification of the original instances.* So what is going on here?

Comment: DataFrame.groupby().apply() has alot of inconsistencies.
For more, you can follow https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9867

Comment: @MohitRajpoot Yea, but that mainly concerns index structure of the returned DataFrames. This here produces wrong results for no apparent reason... maybe I should open an issue in the repo

Comment: I've done some experimentation to understand the `DataFrame.groupby().apply()` function and added them as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When I did

```
def func(x):
    x = x.copy()
    x.sort_values('B', inplace=True)
    return x.B.max()
```

It returns

```
A
a    3
b    1
```

so it verifies your first thought
i.e.

1. that inplace modifies the DataFrame/DataFrameGroupBy itself, while
   the assignment `x = x.sort_values('B')` creates a copy

I iterated over dfg groupby object as well.

```
def func(x):
    x = x.sort_values('B', inplace=True)
    return x.B.max()

dfg = df.groupby('A')
for x in dfg:
    print(func(x[1]))
```

It returns

```
3
1
```

Hence from my understanding, this issue is something to do with how `DataFrame.groupby().apply()` iterates over its elements.
It just assigns same memory block to all it's elements and once you overwrite that block by using `inplace=True`, it gets updated permanently.
Hence your `dfg` and `df` variables still have original values but you're still getting the wrong output.

Comment: can you back the claim "assigns same memory block to all it's elements" somehow? Cause that would be a weird thing to do, IMO, given that groups can have wildly different size...

Comment: in principle, all this should happen on a pretty shallow level of the pandas codebase, so it would just be a matter of looking it up :)

Comment: I've tried to find out some evidence to back this claim but couldn't find anything yet,
I derived it from the above behaviour, so it might be wrong as well.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py

code line 278 in this script, it's clearly mentioned that
`f must not mutate groups. Mutation is not supported and may
  produce unexpected results.`
They haven't mentioned why.
So it could be something to do with memory allocation?